# Getting "Method executeQuery cannot be used for update" for NOT update queries

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, db2

I try to retrieve information about databases and tables of a DB2 System.
The kotlin application successfully connects with the database but when I execute a query (see code below) I always get the error message "Method executeQuery cannot be used for update" even though I do not execute an update query.

```
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(config.connectionString)
    val statement: Statement = connection!!.createStatement()
    val query = "DISPLAY DATABASE"
    //val query = "LIST TABLES"
    val resultSet: ResultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)
```

Error message:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10103][10941][4.29.24] Method executeQuery cannot be used for update. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=null"
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use a valid query (for example, a SELECT statement) because `display database` is not a Db2 query.

Comment: Why is it not a db2 query? You can see here that it is: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=commands-display-database-db2

Comment: because executeQuery() is for SQL statements, and you are using a command (not sql).

Comment: So what would be the equivalent to "show databases" in MySQL, in DB2?

Comment: That depends on the Db2-server operating-system (Z/OS, i-series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud).   Different Db2 platforms have different methods for discovering databases.

Comment: SELECT * FROM [SYSIBM.SYSDATABASE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=tables-sysdatabase) for Db2 for Z/OS?